# How do I do a weighted search over multiple int columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, search, match

I have a table with 6 columns, 1 containing an id, 1 containing a location id and the other 4 containing a range from 1-100. I want to do a query that selects all rows with a specific location id and then order then based on the 4 other range values based on how they match the 4 range values I put in to the search. I guess each "diff" between column_a and input range_a would be a -1, and then sort on that value.

Comment: Interesting problem. Please provide us some sample data and expected results. Thanks.

Comment: I dont understand please..can  you rephrase this.. with an usecase